# Can't get rid of extra characters from bracketed paste when pasting in terminal

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, clipboard

This is getting quite frustrating, but I can't get rid for some reason of the characters that seem to come from a problem involving vim and bracketed paste mode. I sometimes get the extra characters `^[[200~` in front of anything I paste **in my terminal** (not in Vim itself, in which paste works fine).

I've read about paste modes, what bracketed paste is, I've tried fixing that looking at the section about [xterm-bracketed-paste](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#xterm-bracketed-paste) in the Vim manual, but adding `set t_BE=` in my `.vimrc` didn't solve that problem. I've read that I can turn it off with `printf "\e[?2004l"` but that's only solving it once.

I don't know what I am potentially missing or misunderstood, how can I fix that behaviour the right way?

Extra informations:

- I'm running Ubuntu 19.04.
- I'm using zsh with `oh-my-zsh` and only the `git` plugin enabled.
- I use the tilix terminal emulator with the following version info

```
Versions
    Tilix version: 1.8.9
    VTE version: 0.56
    GTK Version: 3.24.8
Tilix Special Features:
    Notifications enabled=0
    Triggers enabled=0
    Badges enabled=1
```

- Vim with the following version info:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 07 2019 11:42:36)
...
+clipboard
...
```

If I've forgotten to provide important information about my setup, don't hesitate to tell me and I'll happily add it.

Comment: Try `Ctrl-Shift-V`, see if that helps?

Comment: @MichaelFrank I've already bound `Ctrl-Shift-V` to the Paste action in TIlix because otherwise `Ctrl-V` is caught by Tilix and Vim does a paste instead of entering visual block mode. So I already paste using that. What would this do otherwise?

Comment: Does your Vim status line say "-- INSERT (paste) --" when this happens?

Comment: @JBL I completely missed the VIM bit, I've noticed that when I am SSH'd into my server, it will still paste with Ctrl-V, but I get that `^[[200~` garbage, but if I use Ctrl-Shift-V, it will paste correctly.

Comment: @grawity I don't get that in Vim, I get that in my terminal when I paste with whatever paste shortcut I have setup. Paste works fine in Vim with `p` when I need it. I've edited the post to emphasize this bit just in case.